# Javamail - sending from localhost instead of godaddy server

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

When I am trying to send a mail from "smtpout.asia.secureserver.net", it is sending from localhost instead of the "secureserver" host.Below is the code :

```
Properties props = new Properties();    
             props.put("mail.smtp.host","smtpout.asia.secureserver.net");       
             props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",    
                       "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");    
             props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");    
             props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
             props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
             props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 

 Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,    
         new javax.mail.Authenticator() {    
         protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {    
         return new PasswordAuthentication("xxxx@xxxxx.net","xxxxx");  
         }    
        });    
        //compose message    
        try {    
         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);    
         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));    
         message.setSubject(sub);    
         message.setText(msg);    
         //send message  
         Transport.send(message);    
         System.out.println("message sent successfully");    
        }
```

catch (MessagingException e) {throw new RuntimeException(e);}

Debug :

```
 com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException
    550 <narasimhatejav@teja> Sender Rejected - MAILFROM must be a valid domain. Ensure the mailfrom domain: "teja"  has a valid MX or A record.
    DEBUG SMTP: got response code 550, with response: 550 <narasimhatejav@teja> Sender Rejected - MAILFROM must be a valid domain. Ensure the mailfrom domain: "teja"  has a valid MX or A record.
```

But if i change the host to "smtp.gmail.com" it is working fine.

Comment: have you made sure "teja" is a valid domain?

Comment: @mhasan .... teja is name of localhost,I am trying to send it from godaddy mail server.But it is trying to send it from localhost.

Comment: How are you setting who the email is from?

Comment: @Jeremy .... In thenew javax.mail.Authenticator(){ PasswordAuthentication(xxxxx@xxxxx.net,password)}

Comment: OK, the error specifically says `<narasimhatejav@teja> Sender Rejected - MAILFROM must be a valid domain.` So you must be setting it somewhere incorrectly. That's why I asked how you are setting it. Show your code.

Comment: @Jeremy.....that is the whole code

Comment: Try calling `message.setFrom("you@example.com")`

Comment: @Jeremy .... setFrom is not accepting any arguments...

Comment: https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setFrom-java.lang.String-

Comment: @Jeremy...let me check on that i am using java mail  v1.4.2....that function is added in v1.5

Comment: @Jeremy....It Worked...

Answer (score 0):

Change the Java mail Jar to v1.5+ and add void javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.setFrom(String address) function

Answer (score 0):

It's sending from localhost because you made most of the [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

The MAILFROM problem is because the host name or name service is misconfigured on your machine.  As a workaround you can set the [`mail.smtp.localhost`](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html#mail.smtp.localhost) property.